Show that if $I_C =C \frac{dV_C}{dt}$ and $V_C=\cos(\omega t)$ then $\frac{V_C}{I_C} = \frac{1}{i\omega C}$

A capacitor is a component that fulfills the relationship $I_C(t) = C \frac{\text{d}V_C(t)}{\text{d}t}$. Show that if $V_C(t) = \cos(\omega t)$ then the capacitor's impedance is $Z_C = \frac{V_C}{I_C}=\frac{1}{i\omega C}$.

If $V_C(t) = \cos(\omega t)$ then the current is
$$\begin{align*} I_C(t) &= \omega C\Big(-\sin(\omega t)\Big) \\\\
&= \omega C\cos \bigg(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2} \bigg) \\\\
&= \omega C \: \text{Re}\bigg(e^{i(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{2})} \bigg) \\\\
&= \omega C \: \text{Re} \bigg(e^{i\omega t}e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}} \bigg) \end{align*} $$
Here I'm stuck. If I somehow could get that $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$ out of the $\text{Re}$ operator I would be good but I'm not sure how to do that or if that is valid. How can I proceed from here?

Conventionally, the (complex) impedance is computed from the complex phasors instead of the real sinusoidal signals. In consequence, one has $V_C = \cos(\omega t) \equiv e^{j\omega t}$, hence $I_C = C\dot{V}_C = j\omega Ce^{j\omega t}$ and finally $Z_C = \frac{V_C}{I_C} = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$.
